# User Login only in Firecheckout possible

Tags: checkout, magento-1, login

a customer just complaint he cant login.....
When I open the Page and try to Login....it not possible, I will be redirected to the Login Page.
Amazon Login same error.

With Google Login, no Errors.
On Checkout (Firecheckout) login is also possible.....

I already did the Cookie Settings.

Comment: Is there a formkey in the login form?